# How to arrange the json data?

Tags: json, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

This is how i get the json data

```
"wrk_hours": [{"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Tuesday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Wednesday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Thursday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Friday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Saturday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Sunday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Monday"}]
```

So, i need to arrange it from monday to sunday .
If some days are missing.. i need to print as closed. How can I able to obtain the same from the above data.

Currently I am doing as

```
<table bgcolor="#00FF00" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#577c14">
      <th v-for="(item,key) in work" :key="key">
        <span v-if="new Date().getDay()-1==key" class="today">{{item.day}}</span>
        <span v-else-if="new Date().getDay()==key" class="tomorrow">{{item.day}}</span>
        <span v-else class="all">{{item.day}}</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="(item,key) in work" :key="key">
         <span v-if="new Date().getDay()-1==key" class="today">{{item.opens_at}} to {{item.closes_at}}</span>
        <span v-else-if="new Date().getDay()==key" class="tomorrow">{{item.opens_at}} to {{item.closes_at}}</span>
        <span v-else >{{item.opens_at}} to {{item.closes_at}}</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
         </tbody>
                </table>
```

But when I do this way, data is coming as the same way in the data, I need to arrange the data as monday,tuesday,wedenesday..... sunday.

Sometimes. i get data as

```
"wrk_hours": [{"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Sunday"},{"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Tuesday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Wednesday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Friday"},{"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Monday"}]
```

so here thursday and saturday are missing. So, i need to print as closed. So, how can i able to achieve the same. Please help o obtain the result?

My vue js code is

```
new Vue({ 
 el: '#feed' , 
 data: { 
 data: [], 
 work: '',
 pid: ''
 }, 
 mounted() { 
this.$nextTick(function() {    
data['pid'] = this.pid;
 $.ajax({ 
 url: "https://need2spot.com/alpha/get/post/", 
 data: data,
 type: "POST",
 dataType: 'json', 
 success: function (e) { 
 if (e.status == 1) { 
  self.data = e.data;
  self.reviews = e.data['reviews'];
  self.work = e.data['wrk_hours'];
  console.log(self.wrk_hours)
}
}
});
}) 
 }, 
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate your JSON before displaying the data.
Create an array that will maintain the list of days in specific order you want. Then, match your wrk_hours array's day with dayList Array(using Array.indexOf). Push the result in that particular position in a new Array. The newArray's index will be empty if some particular day is missing other wise it will contain the result in the particular order you want.

```js
function getNewArray(object){
  newData = []
  object.forEach((obj) => {
   index = days.indexOf(obj.day.toLowerCase())
   newData[index] = obj
  })
  return newData
}
data = {"wrk_hours": [{"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Tuesday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Wednesday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Thursday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Friday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Saturday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Sunday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Monday"}]}

//Order in which you want days list to be created
days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]

console.log(getNewArray(data.wrk_hours))

data2 = {"wrk_hours": [{"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Sunday"},{"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Tuesday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Wednesday"}, {"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Friday"},{"opens_at": "09:00:00", "closes_at": "23:00:00", "day": "Monday"}]}

//If thurday is not present, the new array will have that index empty. You can check for it to print closed
console.log(getNewArray(data2.wrk_hours))
```

Hope it helps